# How to connect heart monitor to Kinect?

Tags: ea-sports-active, kinect

I tried to do it like they do on video, however the light on the heart rate monitor is always blinking and it is not recognized.

I have tried to start the heart monitor(by pressing the on button). it has started blinking. Then I have pressed the connect button on the monitor. Than I have pressed the connect button on xbox. The xbox's ring has started to spin. After some time it has stopped. The blinking on the monitor has not stopped. The game does not see the monitor.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm assuming this question does *not* have to deal with Pokemon Heart Gold...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(This question is about EA Sports Active 2.)

You are basically following the right procedure. This is actually exactly the same procedure as linking any other wireless controller

It helps to hold down the button for a *second* or so on both the controller (monitor) and the XBox itself, not just press it briefly. I believe both will start spinning lights, not just blinking.

You'll want to start with the controller first, and then do the XBox.